# How to apply filter for Screen Views in google analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

My Question is very simple.I have implemented google analytics in my Android App.Everything is working perfectly.There is no problem in my code.

But i am encountering a little problem in using google analytics console. i want to apply filter for screen views in google analytics.Given below i attached the picture for complete understanding.

[Google Analytics Console Picture for complete understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve57i.png)
[image]

I have pointed out filter in picture that is showing the screens Name of my android app for last 30 min. i believe that is default filter of google analytics for screen views.i want to see it for Last one hour OR Last two hour OR Last day.

So what should i do for apply filter for last hour or day?

**Note**: I want to see the same table that is in attached picture. i don't want the customization report because there is not mention the screen name,app version,screen views in customization report.There is just showing the count of screen views.but i want to see the same table that is showing the attached picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: no you can't

Google Analytics has 2 reporting Api, the core and the realtime. Both api has more or less the same behaviour in the api and in the interface . So in this case can be applied to the interface and the API

The first one is used in all the report (except that section), this report usually takes 24-48 hours in processing for free user and a couple of hours for premium, here is where the data is more flexible and more robust. Due this processing time, it's not recomendable to do in that way, the data will be a mess. This is you option if you want to get the last day by hour and minutes (seconds are not available).

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

The other api, the real time, it's not so solid, and has the limit of 30 minutes (can be less with the filter rt:minutesAgo) This api enables to you get the information by each second on the last minute or the information on each minute of the last 30 min.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638637?hl=en

Greetings